# How can I update my Listview from a Delete button in my custom row?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have built a custom row for my ListView which shows the contents of the users Cart. I've added a Button so that they can delete any row they want to. The code for the start of my adapter is below.

```
public class CartDetailAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CartDetail> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    CartDetail data[] = null;

    public CartDetailAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, CartDetail[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }
```

You can see that my data is of type CartDetail which is a class which lists all the items in my custom row. The code I've set out for my removeBttn is set out in getView().

```
holder.removeBttn = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.removeBttn);
holder.removeBttn.setTag(position);

holder.removeBttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Integer index = (Integer) finalHolder.removeBttn.getTag();
        data.remove(index.intValue());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

As my data variable is of type CartDetail[] and not ArrayList, I cannot use remove to delete the item from my list. How can I remove an item from CartDetail[], do I need to create my own method?

Comment: Better you use `ArrayList` because it has remove method which could delete element automatically and maintain position of other elements automatically also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really delete data from an array, so I suggest to use ArrayList instead, but if you insist you can use this method.

```
List<CardDetail> list = new ArrayList<CardDetail>(Arrays.asList(data));
list.remove(position);
data = list.toArray();
```

Comment: list and data are always incompatible. Thank you for all answers, I've changed my data to ArrayList which now works fine..

Answer (score 0):

You should use ArrayList rather than CartDetail data[]

Also, you are already setting tag in view, so you can use click listener in fragment and remove item from list array and notify data set change on adapter as:

Override notify method in Adapter:

```
public void notifyDataSetChanged(List<CartDetail> items){
   this.list = items;
   super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and from fragment:

```
  View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //remove element using v.getTag() from array.
            notifyDataSetChanged(dataset) // new data set
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ArrayList` instead of an normal array because a normal array cannot delete any data from it but an `ArrayList` can so use it and write a delete function inside your adapter class

```
public void deleteEntry(int position){
    arrayList.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

call this function from for deleting for e.g.:

```
adapter.delete(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array Adaptor internally maintains the Array as ArrayList. So you can directly call the remove(Object o) on your Adaptor object.

Don't forgot to call the notifyDataSetChanged on adaptor Object after removing the Object.

Answer (score -2):

Do this in your code I hope its will help you.

```
holder.removeBttn = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.removeBttn);
holder.removeBttn.setTag(position);

holder.removeBttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        data.remove(position);
        data.trimToSize();
        CartDetailAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

May be you can delete your row. Try this.

Comment: array does not have trimToSize() method.

Comment: try without  trimToSize(). Or ArrayList is batter then the simple Array. Thank You